# Cygwin scp directory path

Tags: cygwin, scp

In Cygwin I can execute commands like this:

```
ls -l d:/folder
mkdir d:/folder/anotherfolder
```

But for some reason `scp` doesn't want to work like this:

```
$ scp -r username@ipaddr:d:/remote/folder d:/folder
ssh: Could not resolve hostname d: Name or service not known
```

But it works like this:

```
$ scp -r username@ipaddr:d:/remote/folder /cygdrive/d/folder
```

Any other command works with paths like "d:/folder", only `scp` don't.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/cygdrive/d/folder` is the default POSIX way. All cygwin programs recognize it.
So use it as your default.

`d:/folder` is an old compatilbility trick, but most of the current Cygwin programs do NOT recognize it.
It is usually implemented as Cygwin specific patch of upstream source.

Comment: Well, it is a shame. Thank you for letting me know.